# Which CSS hack can pass the w3c validation?

Tags: css, xhtml

Which css hacks we use to make layout cross browser compatible

- Can pass W3C validation
- Will work forever
- Will never create in any future
  browser versions

What are alternatives which can pass the w3c validation for popular CSS hack which are not valid?

**for example**

underscore hack, `zoom:1` etc.

my purpose is to make a list of **W3C validated and non problematic CSS hacks** and techniques which can be helpful to make CSS layouts cross browser compatible.

mainly we use CSS hacks for IE , but sometime we need Hacks for other desktop browsers also.

Main Concerned browsers are:

- IE6, IE7, IE8
- Safari latest final release
- Firefox 3.6, 3.5 , 3.0 and 2.0
- Opera Latest final release
- Google Chrome latest

Comment: @ji +1 for css hacks... love to get some answers...

Comment: If you want something that will surely not break in future browser versions, *don't* use in-CSS hacks but rather conditional comments to include additional style sheets. They were designed exactly for this purpose and don't rely on browser bugs.

Comment: you are right but for small sites where we need hacks only some specific cases then i like to keep in main css in place to write and manage different CSS for IE for just 7-8 code lines

Comment: then * html selector (for IE6) is probably the safest one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the list:

1. Easy selectors
2. Minimized attribute selectors
3. !important
4. @import "non-ie.css" all;
5. body[class|="page-body"]

They are listed here: [In-CSS Hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css).

However, nobody promise they will work forever.

The best approch for IE hacks is to use conditional comments.

Comment: _property: value, body:empty are not W3C valid

Comment: @Jitendra Of course they are'nt. Look only at "In-CSS Hacks". You look at "Unrecommended hacks".

Comment: "However, nobody promise they will work forever." Why you mean if future Microsoft can release patch for IE6 and 7

Comment: @Jitendra IE6 is not supported anymore. And I don't think it will happen for IE7 neither. but I'm talking about future versions, like IE9. You can't know in advance how it will handle them. So the safest approach is to use conditional comments.